# How do you clean battery corrosion?

Tags: battery, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use coca cola or baking soda + water to clean my battery clamps?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/should-i-use-coca-cola-or-baking-soda-water-to-clean-my-battery-clamps)

My roommate's car wouldn't start, and we found a ton of corrosion on the battery posts. He heard you can clean it off with coca-cola. It seemed to work pretty well, but what's the best way to clean off corrosion? Should the wires be disconnected, or any other precautions taken?

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the battery, and take it out. You can clean the battery with coca-cola as it is the king of the cheap anti corrosives (or remover of corrosion).

Do not confuse corrosion with the sulphate. The white thing on the battery can be easily removed with hot watter and latter a bit of coca-cola.

There are some products that you can get in store, but as a cheap solution and answer to your question Yes you can use coca-cola.

Remember
Put the battery on a place where any spills can be collected. 
Don't dump the content of the battery on places where animal or other forms of life can be affected.